# HTML Create an Equal Size Square Grid Picture System

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

How do I create a picture grid system with equal size squares vertically and horizontally alligned? This is a 2 by 2 picture system below. For some reason the images are unalligned.
I want to be able to customize square later to make them rectangle with certain measurements if needed.
Prefer to utilize bootstrap also

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><img src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&preset=gallery-tab-main-image"></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7"></div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png"></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5b86fce8900cb57bbfd1e7ee/master/w_582,c_limit/Jaguar_I-PACE_S_Indus-Silver_065.jpgColumn"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **flex utilities** & **images from content** of bootstrap
Here are the reference links 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/

I have used those and worked for me! Hope that'd help you also

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 justify-content-center d-flex"><img class="img-thumbnail w-50" src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&preset=gallery-tab-main-image"></div>
    <div class="col-6 justify-content-center d-flex"><img class="img-thumbnail w-50" src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7"></div>
    
    <div class="col-6 justify-content-center d-flex"><img class="img-thumbnail w-50" src="https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png"></div>
    <div class="col-6 justify-content-center d-flex"><img class="img-thumbnail w-50" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5b86fce8900cb57bbfd1e7ee/master/w_582,c_limit/Jaguar_I-PACE_S_Indus-Silver_065.jpgColumn"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks. how do I bring pictures closer together? right now they are too far apart

Comment: also,is there a way to specify the divider width between first column and second column once the pictures are fully expanded into the square? thanks

Comment: It became small because of the bootstrap class i have used w-50. You can remove that to make it's width 100%. And it's aligned centered that's why seems far. You can go through the link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp (css grid) to make them look how you want! Also if you want you can remove img-thumbnail class and check if that helps to get your desired layout

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by setting  `background-image`to your `div`

```css
.img-1 {
  background: url(https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  background-position:center
}

.img-2 {
  background: url(https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&preset=gallery-tab-main-image) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  background-position:center;
}

.img-3 {
  background: url(https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png) no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  height: 300px;
  background-position:center
}

.img-4 {
  background: url(https://media.wired.com/photos/5b86fce8900cb57bbfd1e7ee/master/w_582,c_limit/Jaguar_I-PACE_S_Indus-Silver_065.jpgColumn) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  background-position:center
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row w-100">
    <div class="col img-2"></div>
    <div class="col img-1"></div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col img-3"></div>
    <div class="col img-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are looking to make the image fit completely in the `col` you can use bootstrap classes `w-100` and `h-100` for your images

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 p-0"><img src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&preset=gallery-tab-main-image" class="w-100 h-100"></div>
    <div class="col-6 p-0"><img src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7" class="w-100 h-100"></div>
   
    <div class="col-6 p-0"><img src="https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png" class="w-100 h-100"></div>
    <div class="col-6 p-0"><img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5b86fce8900cb57bbfd1e7ee/master/w_582,c_limit/Jaguar_I-PACE_S_Indus-Silver_065.jpgColumn" class="w-100 h-100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if I wanted 3 by 3. or 4 by 4, I may have to dynamically edit css? or is there easier way? thanks

Comment: You can do dynamically with JavaScript. As per your requirement. You need to append the div

Comment: thanks! finally got it working, what's best practice? flex in bootstrap like nazifa answer or this? seems like flex is designed specifically for this, just trying to learn, feels like I should not inject websites in css.  just formats

Comment: Bootstrap row uses flex by default. This is another way to make make your images to fit inside the column. It scales accordingly. Please accept the answer which you feel was helpful. Happy coding

Comment: if you can remove the url from css and place in html,would happy to accept, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For doing that, you can use the [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

It is very simple to use with Bootstrap, follow the reworked example I made for you in the following CodePen on [this link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PrEPGa). 
If you don't want to wrap images 2 by 2 but doing it automatically, you can do it [this way](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YoYyEY) too.

Thanks to the `col-6`, it's going to automatically take 6 columns of the 12 of Bootstrap. Of course you can change it following the screen size because of the classes like `col-{breakpoint}-{columns}.`

If you have any question, do not hesitate.

---

Good luck.

Comment: Hi  first link does not work.  second link does  thanks

Comment: finally got first link working,  I want the pictures expanded into each box, equal length and height, right now picture in upper right of apples are smaller

Comment: if you ever tried narrow the width of the browser window also, the pictures overlap and collide with each other.  thanks