# HTML Specify Divider gap measurement in Square Grid Picture

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a square grid, how do I specify the white space divider gap between First Column and Second Column? Right now they seem to far apart, I would like to be able to specify measurements between first column and second column, but keep the pictures in a square shape.
see green arrow in picture link below. being able to specify row divider measurement would also be nice
Thanks,

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <title>JS Bin</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 justify-content-center d-flex"><img class="img-thumbnail w-100" src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&preset=gallery-tab-main-image"></div>
  <div class="col-6 justify-content-center d-flex"><img class="img-thumbnail w-100" src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7"></div>
  
  <div class="col-6 justify-content-center d-flex"><img class="img-thumbnail w-100" src="https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png"></div>
  <div class="col-6 justify-content-center d-flex"><img class="img-thumbnail w-100" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5b86fce8900cb57bbfd1e7ee/master/w_582,c_limit/Jaguar_I-PACE_S_Indus-Silver_065.jpgColumn"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

[image]

Related to question
[HTML Create an Equal Size Square Grid Picture System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56802507/html-create-an-equal-size-square-grid-system)

Answer (score 0):

to do this you should override `col-6` class and change the padding as you want.

It's recommended to add other class to adjust padding rather than editing `col-6` class.

`col-6` set by default in bootstrap to

```
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
```

I've added class `nopadding` with style:

```
.col-6.nopadding{ 
   padding: 0;
}
```

If you want to remove the space between image and border, you would also remove the padding of img. Fortunately it has class `img-thumbnail` so you'd add:

```
.nopadding .img-thumbnail { 
padding: 0;
}
```

See the final result:

```css
.col-6.nopadding{ 
padding: 0;
}

.nopadding .img-thumbnail { 
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 nopadding justify-content-center d-flex"><img class="img-thumbnail w-100" src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&preset=gallery-tab-main-image"></div>
    <div class="col-6 nopadding justify-content-center d-flex"><img class="img-thumbnail w-100" src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7"></div>

    <div class="col-6 nopadding justify-content-center d-flex"><img class="img-thumbnail w-100" src="https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png"></div>
    <div class="col-6 nopadding justify-content-center d-flex"><img class="img-thumbnail w-100" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5b86fce8900cb57bbfd1e7ee/master/w_582,c_limit/Jaguar_I-PACE_S_Indus-Silver_065.jpgColumn"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can remove all padding by setting: `padding: 0`

Comment: when I change padding to 0, I still see a small space, how do resolve pictures touch edge to edge?

Comment: you mean the space between image and border ?

Comment: if yes: I've updated the post to match your answer. Check it please